# Disproportionation reactions

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, applied-chemistry

Are there any examples of a disproportionation reaction being harnessed to do useful electrical work? It is of course possible in a comproportionation reactions, such as a lead-acid cell.

Comment: How would it know which way to work?

Comment: Electrochemical reactions from which we can harness electrical work **must** involve the trasfer of electrons through an electrolyte/electrode interface. Afterwards, they can travel externally and we can use them. In lead-acid batteries, you may "say" that you we comproportionation because lead ($0$) and lead(IV) oxide ($+4$) react and give lead(II) sulphate ($+2$). However, this is the sum of individual reactions that *do* take place in the cell. The global reaction is just an addition to help us, but strictly speaking, it doesn't take place anywhere in the cell.